Let $\mathcal{M}$ be any linear subset of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Prove that $\mathcal{M}^{\perp}$ is a closed linear subspace .
So I am stuck again while proving this theorem. I showed that any sequence lets say $y_n = x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{\alpha_{j}},x)x_{\alpha_{j}} \in \mathcal{M}^{\perp}$  is a cauchy sequence. I did it by the following argument
$$||y_m-y_n||=||\sum_{j=n+1}^{m}(x_{\alpha_{j}},x)x_{\alpha_{j}}||=\sum_{j=n+1}|(x_{\alpha_{j}},x)|^2 \leq ||x||^2$$
So $\left\{ y_n \right\}$'s are cauchy so they converges. Now i can't think of any way to show that the limit point in in $\mathcal{M}^{\perp}$. I feel like I have seen some where a theorem regarding the limit being in the subspace but couldn't remember it. Can anyone give me a hint or something? I don't need the full solution.

By this post we have the the inner product is a continuos map, in particular, if $y_n \in M^\perp$ is a convergent sequence with limit $y$ we have, for any $x \in M$
$$
0= \lim_n(x,y_n)=(x,y)
$$
So $y \in M^\perp$
